# Statefulsets in K8S are being recreated after deletion

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm playing with the Elasticsearch operator Kubernetes and created two stateful sets (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-orchestration.html):

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.12.1
  nodeSets:
  - name: master-nodes
    count: 3
    config:
      node.roles: ["master"]
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        storageClassName: standard
  - name: data-nodes
    count: 3
    config:
      node.roles: ["data"]
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        storageClassName: standard
```

The problem is that I cannot delete the stateful sets. After deletion, they're recreated automatically:

```
my-PC:~$ kubectl get sts
NAME                         READY   AGE
quickstart-es-data-nodes     0/0     14m
quickstart-es-master-nodes   0/0     18m
my-PC:~$ kubectl delete sts quickstart-es-data-nodes --force --grace-period=0
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
statefulset.apps "quickstart-es-data-nodes" force deleted
my-PC:~$ kubectl get sts
NAME                         READY   AGE
quickstart-es-data-nodes     0/3     3s
quickstart-es-master-nodes   0/0     18m
```

Before deletion I already scaled down the statefulset to 0 to ensure that all pods are terminated. But after deletion, the stateful is recreated (see quickstart-es-data-nodes).

So, anyone having any idea how I can delete the stateful sets without being recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer... I need to run the following command for deletion:

`kubectl delete elasticsearch quickstart`

This finally removed the quickstart examples.

Answer (score 3):

it's due to the operator you are using for the Elasticsearch. Operator manage the **statefulset** and will update if you delete it.

> Behind the scenes, ECK translates each NodeSet specified in the
> Elasticsearch resource into a StatefulSet in Kubernetes.

if you read the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-orchestration.html#k8s-statefulsets

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#on-delete

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the custom object. The operator owns those StatefulSets and will continually update them to match its expected content.